# How to implement duties using PWM?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pwm, texas-instruments

I have a microcontroller from based on an Evaluation Kit of Texas Instruments.
There is a vibration motor which is being activated with following code:

`handle = ClipPWM_open(PWMI_MOTOR, &pwm_params);
PWM_start(handle);
uint8_t intensity = 100;
PWM_setDuty(handle, intensity * 155)`
[(PWM.h reference TI)](http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/tirtos/2_20_00_06/exports/tirtos_full_2_20_00_06/products/tidrivers_full_2_20_00_08/docs/doxygen/html/_p_w_m_8h.html)

My task is to develop a function which will activate the vibration motor and start from X and ends at Y. This is executed in a specified amount of ticks.

Firstly, I tried to enable the motor, set the intensity (e.g. 10), wait using a for loop until half of ticks were reached. After that I added the intensity setting to another value (e.g. 100) to wait again using a for loop.

This won't work. the intensity of 10 (the first) is being ignored and it only executes the intensity of 100.

I'm new to these topics. Do I have the wrong approach?

Comment: Reading `PWM_setDuty` doc, it seems that an error has occurred: " If an error occurs while calling the function the PWM duty cycle will remain unchanged." Can you retrieve the error?

Comment: @ferdepe Hello, no unfortunately not. It returns PWM_STATUS_SUCCESS (0) at any time.

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to see whether there is a PWM at all.  It may be that a level of 10 is in the dead-band of the motor - i.e. insufficient to overcome the motor's inertia and friction.

Comment: What does `ClipPWM_open` do?  The link provided documents `PWM_open`.

Comment: What are the values of the `pwm_params` members?  The question is unanswerable without knowing how you configured the PWM, because the `intensity` argument semantics depend upon that.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Your code doesn't show the calls to `PWM_init` and `PWM_Params_init`. You also don't have the delay you mentined. You also don't check if `handle` is `NULL` after `PWM_open`. Also, it's unclear what `ClipPWM_open` is, this function is not mentioned in the link you posted. Right now, this question is unanswerable.